# How to use methods from extended class on objects from main class? [JAVA]

Tags: java, android, class, android-studio, extends

I'm starting with developing something, and I have few classes that are using the same methods, so I want to have it in one class (to easy fixing in one place etc). Problem is that I dont know how to use methods from different classes on object in main class. Code for explanation:

```js
public class A extends C {
 public UiDevice device;
 
 device = UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation());
 
 public void test(){
  methodFromC();
 }
}
public class B extends C {
 public UiDevice device;
 
 device = UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation());
 
 public void test(){
  methodFromC();
 }
}
public class C {
  protected void methodFromC(){
   device.something();
  }
}
```

I know that I can do it by adding argument to methodFromC:

```
public class C {
 protected void methodFromC(UiDevice device){
     device.something();
 }
```

and running it by

```
methodFromC(device);
```

But maybe is there better solution?

Comment: Your code wont even compile and hence a proper suggestion can't be made. Your class C uses device, but the device is neither an instance variable nor the method argument. If you think class C would need UiDevice to work, it should be an instance variable. If methodFromC only needs UiDevice, it should be part of method's argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, as a beginning programmer unless you are doing it for school, avoid extending classes.  It ends up a big spaghetti mess until you learn to moderate it (I fell for this one big-time), What you are trying to do isn't good code right now.

I THINK what you are trying to do, however is something like this:

(Assume unspecified code remains pretty much as it is)

```
class A extends C
{
    public UiDevice getDevice()
    {
        return device;
    }
}

abstract class C
{
     public abstract UiDevice getDevice();
     public methodFromC()
     {
         getDevice().doSomethingToDevice();
     }
}
```

This pattern allows you to access something from A in a parent class.

B can also have it's own device.  I believe this is what you are after (C being able to operate on A's device or B's device depending on which one extended C).

Get rid of the public variable.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `super` keyword to access anything from the class you are extending. In your case :

```
public class B extends C {
public UiDevice device;

device = super.methodFromB();

public void test(){
    methodFromB();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If many of your classes declare methods that do the same thing, you can make them inherit from one class, let's call it class A. In class declare and implement the method. Then in child classes declare methods and in their body write:

```
super.nameOfYourMethodFromParentClass();
```

---

In general, to use a method from different class you just create an object of the class and call a method on it. Like:

```
class A {
    public void myMethod() {
        B b = new B();
        b.methodFromB();
    }
}
```

When it comes to inheritance be aware of this:
You can create an object of a class that declares this method or of a class that inherits from the class that declares this method and call the method on this object.

Like:
Class A inherits from C. In class C you have method methodFromC() declared. To invoke method from class C on object from class A you can do:

```
A a = new A();
a.methodFromC(device);
```

The invoked method here is the method from class C.

But if in class A you override method from class C (that means in class A you declare a method that has the same name and parameters as method in class C), then by executing the code I have written above you will invoke the method from class A, not class C.